# How to assign a column in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 2 tables. One table has a list of names while the other table has a list of possible prefixes for those names.

(these arent the real values btw)

```
table1.name:
aunt
australia
au revoir
mint
mi ne
mi
poser
nz25
nz land

table2.prefix:
au
mi
nz
pos
```

I also have a column that tells me whether the prefix starts or ends with it so (dont ask why, i dont know either)

```
table2.type | table2.prefix
starts with | au
ends with   | mi
starts with | nz
ends with   | pos
```

what I have to do is I have to create a query that will list all the prefixes that has the type 'starts with' and then select all the names that start with those prefixes.

I am not allowed to use join so I tried setting a variable.

```
declare @prefix varchar

set @prefix = (select table2.prefix from table2 where table2.type = 'starts with')
select table1.name
from table1
where table2.name like @prefix + '%'
```

I've been pondering for way too long on how to tackle this. Again I can't use join so please let me know if there's a workaround for this.

Comment: What is "I can't use a join" all about - is this a test?

Comment: Not really for a test but the reason I can't join them is they don't have a common column and I'm not really allowed to add or modify any of our existing tables.